How to use docker compose secrets with a non-root user when a file is required
Situation
The current (07/2024) docker compose documentation states (falsely) that there is a long-syntax when using 'docker secrets' that can defines the name, uid, gid and mode of the mounted file
See example and documentaion:
services:
  frontend:
    image: example/webapp
    secrets:
      - source: server-certificate
        target: server.cert
        uid: "103"
        gid: "103"
        mode: 0440
secrets:
  server-certificate:
    file: ./server.cert

This configuration is valid but has no affect at all when using compose (works for docker swarm).
There was an discussion (GitHub Docker Issue 9648) going on about it (showing the different implementations of this specification) but the documentation has not been fixed (GitHub Docker Issue 18907).
Result is a mounted secret (/run/secrets/<foobar>) with root:root (0:0) ownership and permission mode 400.
Sidenote: /run/secrets/ is a read-only mounted filesystem.
Problem
When using docker compose secrets on an image which does come with a non-root user shipped.
services:
    nginx:
        image: nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:1.27-alpine
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        secrets:
            - FOO_BAR_SECRET
secrets:
    FOO_BAR_SECRET:
        file: .foo.bar

Solution idea (question)
Is there another/better solution then creating a custom image (Dockerfile) which switches back to the 'root' user and defines a wrapping docker entrypoint script
FROM nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:1.27-alpine

## switching to non-root user 'nginx' later in custom 'docker-entrypoint-wrapper.sh'
USER root

## one could argue to just use pre-installed 'runuser' instead, or install 'gosu'. For this example there is no strong argument for either
RUN apk update && apk add su-exec

## enables us to run commands on startup as 'root'
RUN mv /docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint-original.sh
COPY docker-entrypoint-wrapper.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod ug+x /docker-entrypoint.sh


that copies those root-exclusive secrets from the read-only filesystem mount elsewhere, updates the file owner to the desired non-root user and switches back to this user to execute the actual/original docker entrypoint script ?
#!/usr/bin/env sh
set -e

mkdir /run/secrets_ \
&& cp -r /run/secrets/* /run/secrets_ \
&& chown -R nginx:nginx /run/secrets_

# as mentioned in the Docker file: may use 'gosu' or 'runuser' instead
exec su-exec nginx /docker-entrypoint-original.sh "${@}"

Solution alternative (question) when a file is not required or just not an option
Qudos to dcendents (GitHub) pointing out this idea (on GitHub Keycloak Issue 10816, that one could 'export' the content of the secret file. Which indeed is not really desired security-wise hence you may not export it but just make it 'inline available' for the command.
#!/bin/sh

## find all secret files mounted by docker
for i in $(ls -1 /run/secrets)
do
    ## export secret file name as environment variable
    export "${i}"="$(cat /run/secrets/${i})"
done

## run actual command
exec "$@"

Research
There is one idea of having just an "simple" docker mount declaration with the desired ownership and permission mode but in that case one would be required to do it for every X different services and Y different secrets, which would lead to an "small" bloat of long repeating lines.
Restrictions/requirements on a solution
(A) I need or would like to have a general solution thats works for a Windows and Linux host. Scripting a chown on a Windows host may not be a way.
(B) The FOO_BAR_SECRET will be used by multiple services (it will be a wildcard TLS certificate) which all requires different UIDs.

Welcome to StackOverflow; interesting question - maybe, you could phrase the Situation description so that it does not seem like a "wontfix bug" but just like a "documentation bug"? cf. https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/9648#issuecomment-1852701204 - as the docker compose implementation and the Compose specification are two different things.

Side question: is there a reason why you suggest using su-exec and not gosu for example? the main use case of the latter being to drop permissions from root to a non-privileged user.

Cont'd: it seems the current release of su-exec does not ship an important fix, cf. https://github.com/tianon/gosu#su-exec

My intention was not to suggest su-exec as "the way" (hence the comment). I actually saw it was used in the image of envoy (proxy), so I just took it here for an example. -- runuser could also be used without a need to install it manually. -- I did not tried gosu, I will mention both in the comment, since right now (on Mobil) I can not check whenever gosu is pre-installed.

No worries! it was not intended to be a criticism, just a minor suggestion - that wouldn't deserve to be an answer :)

FYI @bjoern-nowak: I wasn't able to reproduce the problem on Debian GNU/Linux: using your docker-compose.yml, the /run/secrets/FOO_BAR_SECRET file is readable and owned by 1000:1000 (like the original file .foo.bar). Could you tell what is your OS?

Also, do you use Docker Engine for Linux, or Docker Desktop for Linux/macOS/Windows?

That is quite interresting (!). I'am in fact using "Docker Desktop for windows". I could test (later) on our linux servers whenever I can reproduce it there (just using the "Docker Engine".

As mentioned in docker/compose#9648, docker compose now warns about the fact uid, gid, mode fields are not supported:
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:1.27-alpine
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    secrets:
      - source: foobar
        target: FOO_BAR_SECRET
        uid: "103"
        gid: "103"
        mode: 0440
    entrypoint: '/bin/sh -c "ls -Rhal /run/secrets/; cat /run/secrets/FOO_BAR_SECRET"'
secrets:
  foobar:
    file: .foo.bar

$ docker compose up

↓
WARN[0000] secrets `uid`, `gid` and `mode` are not supported, they will be ignored 

Attaching to nginx-1
nginx-1  | /run/secrets/:
nginx-1  | total 12K    
nginx-1  | drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root        4.0K Jul 19 13:31 .
nginx-1  | drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        4.0K Jul 19 13:31 ..
nginx-1  | -rw-r-----    1 1000     1000          18 Jul 19 13:15 FOO_BAR_SECRET
nginx-1  | cat: can't open '/run/secrets/FOO_BAR_SECRET': Permission denied
nginx-1 exited with code 1

The secret file is not readable, but note that on my workstation (Debian 12) the file is not owned by root:root, but has the same permissions as the source file:
$ ls -l .foo.bar

↓
-rw-r----- 1 user user 18 juil. 19 15:15 .foo.bar

So it appears you have at least one way to address your issue (to be tested on your side):
Check the image's uid

Browsing https://explore.ggcr.dev/?image=nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged

Then following the top digest links lead to:
{
   "config": {
      …
      "User": "101"
   },
   …
}



Apply the uid locally
$ sudo chown 101:101 .foo.bar; sudo chmod 440 .foo.bar

Skip unsupported secret fields in docker-compose.yml
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:1.27-alpine
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    secrets:
      - source: foobar
        target: FOO_BAR_SECRET
    entrypoint: '/bin/sh -c "ls -Rhal /run/secrets/; cat /run/secrets/FOO_BAR_SECRET"'
secrets:
  foobar:
    file: .foo.bar

$ docker compose up

↓
Attaching to nginx-1
nginx-1  | /run/secrets/:
nginx-1  | total 12K    
nginx-1  | drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root        4.0K Jul 19 13:44 .
nginx-1  | drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        4.0K Jul 19 13:44 ..
nginx-1  | -r--r-----    1 nginx    nginx         18 Jul 19 13:15 FOO_BAR_SECRET
nginx-1  | TEST_VAR="VALUE!"
nginx-1 exited with code 0

Side-notes on Docker Engine for Linux vs. Docker Desktop
The above behavior may require directly using Docker Engine (and not Docker Desktop), as you confirmed in the comments.
Indeed, the bind-mount permissions are known to always-default-to-root:root with Docker Desktop (even on Linux), see:

SO: Docker bind mount permissions - unexpected mounting as root:root
GH: docker/desktop-linux#150

⚠️ As another side note, if ever you install Docker Engine for GNU/Linux on a personal workstation, do not add your user account to the docker group as it is suggested in many online tutorials (sudo usermod -aG docker $USER), because this is risky. Just define an alias to avoid typing sudo docker explicitly but still imply sudo to get a a prompt asking for the sudoer password. For details, see this SO answer of mine.

Interesting. Thanks for pointing out about the warning that docker compose.

There are two requirement I did not yet have metions because I though they may not be relevant or makes the question to narrow or complex, sorry for the inconviences. -- (A) I need or would like to have a general solution thats works for a Windows and Linux host. Scripting a chown on a Windows host may not be a way. -- (B) The foobar secret will be used by multiple services (it will be a wildcard TLS certificate) which all requires different UIDs. I see the "compose config" or "image" in-charge of ensuring the correct ownership/permissions, following SoC principle.

Please let me know if I should include these or at least requirement (B) in my post.

Anyway: if that would be the "answer/solution" then we could also use an simple "docker compose volume mount" since this would be as "verbose" as having the "foobar secret" duplicated per service (so that the host can provide different UIDs) -- what I would dislike as descripted in the "Research" chapter of my post.

Sure, you can add (A) and (B) in your post. Obviously this answer does not addresses these two requirements, anyway it was useful to put forth that (A) is important (feel free to vote if you agree ;)

BTW I believe it may be possible to obtain a multi-platform answer addressing "DRY", along the lines of your proposed Dockerfile… I'll try to come up with another answer.

I have updated the post about the restrictions. Really appreciate your help. Just for the protocol, there are no more restrictions I am aware of. -- whenever we or someone else does not find another solution I am willing/happy to accept yours as the answer (in the current state of docker compose)

Following the discussion in the comments of my previous answer, here is another solution, which should be cross-platform, and with a better SoC / DRY:
TL;DR: The OP initially suggested to use a Dockerfile that goes root, adds some layers, and so on, but I'd also suggest to use only one (generic) Dockerfile, and pass values either via build arguments (at build time), or via environment variables (at container run time), all specified in a concise way from the YAML conf file.
Consider this docker-compose.yml:
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: wrap-secret
      args:
        # original image
        image: nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:1.27-alpine
        # original entrypoint file
        entrypoint: "/entrypoint.sh"
    environment:
      target_uid: 101
      target_gid: 101
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    secrets:
      - source: foobar
        target: FOO_BAR_SECRET
secrets:
  foobar:
    file: .foo.bar

With this wrap-secret/Dockerfile:
ARG image
FROM $image
USER root

# BEGIN TAKEN FROM https://github.com/tianon/gosu/blob/master/INSTALL.md
# ASSUMING $image is alpine-based
ENV GOSU_VERSION 1.17
RUN set -eux; \
    \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .gosu-deps \
        ca-certificates \
        dpkg \
        gnupg \
    ; \
    \
    dpkgArch="$(dpkg --print-architecture | awk -F- '{ print $NF }')"; \
    wget -O /usr/local/bin/gosu "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/$GOSU_VERSION/gosu-$dpkgArch"; \
    wget -O /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/$GOSU_VERSION/gosu-$dpkgArch.asc"; \
    \
# verify the signature
    export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)"; \
    gpg --batch --keyserver hkps://keys.openpgp.org --recv-keys B42F6819007F00F88E364FD4036A9C25BF357DD4; \
    gpg --batch --verify /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc /usr/local/bin/gosu; \
    gpgconf --kill all; \
    rm -rf "$GNUPGHOME" /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc; \
    \
# clean up fetch dependencies
    apk del --no-network .gosu-deps; \
    \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gosu; \
# verify that the binary works
    gosu --version; \
    gosu nobody true
# END TAKEN FROM https://github.com/tianon/gosu/blob/master/INSTALL.md

WORKDIR /app
COPY wrap-secret-entrypoint.sh /app/wrap-secret-entrypoint.sh
ARG entrypoint
RUN chmod a+x /app/wrap-secret-entrypoint.sh \
  && sed -e 's@THE_ENTRYPOINT@'"${entrypoint}"'@' -i /app/wrap-secret-entrypoint.sh
# we might want to replace sed with a perl oneliner or so
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/wrap-secret-entrypoint.sh"]

And this script wrap-secret-entrypoint.sh:
#!/usr/bin/env sh
set -e
entrypoint="THE_ENTRYPOINT"
[ -n "$target_uid" ]
[ -n "$target_gid" ]
# we might also pass target_mode…
mkdir /run/secrets_
cp -a /run/secrets/* /run/secrets_/
chown -R "$target_uid:$target_gid" /run/secrets_
# we might use 'su-exec' or 'runuser' instead
exec gosu "$target_uid:$target_gid" "$entrypoint" "$@"

Then run docker compose up --build.
What do you think?
Side-note:
In your original post, you had written something like:
set -e
cmd1 && cmd2

which is buggy, use ( cmd && cmd2 ) instead or cmd1 ; cmd2.

Hi @bjoern-nowak !, sorry for the ping - did you get a chance to test this solution?
